# parquet to spark dataframe with location column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to read in a parquet file into a Dataframe using spark. My requirement is to create another column in the dataframe using the parquet path of the parquet file.

Eg: I have parquet files in the following path in hdfs:
/event/2018-01-01/abc/xyz=10/parquet1.parquet
/event/2018-01-01/abc/xyz=10/parquet2.parquet

I want to read all the files in /event/2018-01-01/abc and create a column "dt" in the dataframe which specifies the date in the path. How do I extract the date from the path and create it as a column in the spark dataframe?

Comment: first you must attempt to solve it and share your difficulties. And then you can get great helps from us.

Comment: Thanks. found it. Can use input_file_path() to get the filename,